# How to prevent Google Translate from displaying both the translated text and original text in a React-Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, translation, google-translate

**Google Translate is showing both the translated text and the original text. How to solve this issue?**
I have integrated Google translate script in my website.
"https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit";
When I select any language from the dropdown , initially the webpage is translated correctly. But when I do interaction with my website of any kind - scroll , touch , button click , link text click etc. , the translated text as well as the original text appears at the simultaneously.
This is the image before translation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jee63.png)

Image after translation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhS4d.png)

Below is the code snippet used for integrating the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
         new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
            google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, autoDisplay: 
            false, includedLanguages: 'en,hi,bn,mr,ta,gu,kn,te'}, 'google_translate_element');
      }
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

`<div id="google_translate_element"></div>`

Below is the function used to display the icon and removing the google translate banner from header.

```
updateTransator(){
        let googleLogo = document.getElementsByClassName('VIpgJd-ZVi9od-l4eHX-hSRGPd');
        googleLogo && googleLogo[0] ? googleLogo[0].style.display = 'none':'';
        let googleProcessLogo = document.getElementsByClassName('VIpgJd-ZVi9od-aZ2wEe-wOHMyf');
        googleProcessLogo && googleProcessLogo[0] ? googleProcessLogo[0].style.display = 'none':'';
        let selectDiv = document.getElementById(':0.targetLanguage');
        let icon = document.createElement('i');
        selectDiv.appendChild(icon);
        selectDiv.children[0]?selectDiv.children[0].classList.remove('goog-te-combo'):'';
        selectDiv.children[0]?selectDiv.children[0].classList.add('google-translatorSelectDiv'):'';
        selectDiv.children[1]?selectDiv.children[1].classList.add('google-translatorDiv'):'';
        let googleText = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-gadget');
        googleText && googleText[0] ? googleText[0].style = 'color:rgb(10, 166, 153);':'';
        
      }
```